# Generate a dataframe from list with different length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here I got many list with different length, like `a=[1,2,3]` and `b=[2,3]`

I would like to generate a pd.DataFrame from them, by padding `nan` at the end of list, like this:

```
   a  b
1  1  2 
2  2  3
3  3  nan
```

Any good idea to help me do so?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use

```
In [9]: pd.DataFrame({'a': pd.Series(a), 'b': pd.Series(b)})
Out[9]:
   a    b
0  1  2.0
1  2  3.0
2  3  NaN
```

Or,

```
In [10]: pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a': a, 'b': b}, orient='index').T
Out[10]:
     a    b
0  1.0  2.0
1  2.0  3.0
2  3.0  NaN
```