# How to create a Pandas DataFrame with columns?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Basically, I have 2 lists in python

```
list1 = ['Archaeology', 'Astronomy', 'Biology', 'Botany']
list2 = ['soccer', 'basketball', 'tennis', 'baseball', 'golf', 'running', 'volleyball']
```

And now, I want to create a DataFrame in Pandas that looks like this :

[image: (Image) How I want the DataFrame to look]

How do I go about this task ?

Comment: Why? The organization of pandas implies that there _is_ a relationship for values stored within the same row, but in your case this doesn't seem to be true. Why not use separate Series, perhaps storing them in a container like a dict?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you e. g. tried creating an empty dataframe and assigning those lists as series?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Take multiple lists into dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522724/take-multiple-lists-into-dataframe)

Comment: @DJK it won't work with dictionaries as the list are of different lengths

Comment: @mozway, seems more like a minor nuance of the problem, does stackoverflow need every single variant of every single problem? [Heres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49891200/generate-a-dataframe-from-list-with-different-length) another identical Q/A

Comment: @DJK well, sure this is basic, but in my opinion it doesn't take much time to provide the answer and might help a beginner keep enthusiasm ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `pandas.DataFrame` constructor. You can't construct it as columns directly as the number of elements is unequal ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522724/take-multiple-lists-into-dataframe) wouldn't work), but you can make it as rows and transpose:

```
pd.DataFrame([list1, list2], index=['academics', 'sports']).T
```

output:

```
     academics      sports
0  Archaeology      soccer
1    Astronomy  basketball
2      Biology      tennis
3       Botany    baseball
4         None        golf
5         None     running
6         None  volleyball
```